# Sinon alert stub: "Attempted to wrap alert which is already wrapped"

Tags: javascript, qunit, sinon

I'm using Sinon 1.14. I would like to suppress all javascript alerts using Sinon's stubs.

Using the latest Chrome version: `42.0.2311.135 m`, I get an exception: "Attempted to wrap alert which is already wrapped"

The code below works fine in latest Firefox. I will update with a fiddle.

```
var hooks = {

    beforeEach: function(assert){
        this.sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
        this.sandbox.stub(window, 'alert', function (msg) { return false; });
    },

    afterEach: function(){
        this.sandbox.restore();
    }
};

module('example', hooks);

test('example', function(assert){
    ok(true, 'does not throw an exception');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating Sinon from 1.14 to 1.14.1 seems to do the trick. I assume this was a bug?

As a side note, the code runs fine in 1.12 as well.

Comment: The +1 is for your comment above: "Please note the this.sandbox.restore(); after each test. That should prevent it from wrapping twice". You should add it to the answer: I'm using version 2.1.0 and still got the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

`window.alert` is a global function. Every time `beforeEach` runs it will replace that function with a wrapped function. I guess Sinon prevents you from wrapping a function twice.

You can either make sure to have a setup function that runs only once.

Or modify your code so that you don't have global dependencies (ie. pass in a reference to `alert` or a delegating `window` object). This can impact your code architecture a lot. This also shows why it is important to think about testing when designing your architecture.

Comment: Please note the `this.sandbox.restore();` after each test. That should prevent it from wrapping twice

Comment: Maybe `this` in `afterEach` is not the same as `this` in `beforeEach`? Verify that the function is unwrapped.

Comment: It is. If I inspect the sandbox before and after `restore()`, it gets emptied correctly...